# WP CLI Core install - blank database

Tags: database, wp-cli

A very strange thing has started happenning with my local WP installs...

I am using latest version of MAMP Pro, and running:

wp core install --url="http://example.local" --title="example" --admin_user="exa-admin" --admin_password="1234567" --admin_email="xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"

Doesn't do anything. the database which is created fine with 'wp db create' remains devoid of tables - empty.

The install command seems to run with no error, but I am lost. I don't get any DB connectivity errors, but obviously when viewing the site it launches the 'famous 5 minute install' as there is no data in the DB.

I have run this thing loads of times in the past with no issue. I don't think it's anything to do with the PHP version, but I am thinking I am missing something obvious.

Are there logs? can I run in verbose mode?

thanks all.

Comment: and where is `wp core config --dbname=$1 --dbuser=root --dbpass=***`

Comment: Yes, that's in there too otherwise 'wp db create' wouldn't work. I could show the whole script but don't think it's necessary. thanks

Comment: but have you created the user in mysql/mariadb?

Comment: Yes. the user is root, and the pass also root. I'm thinking if no user then I would have connectivity issues, but I can still continue with the manual install process - or am I missing something. thanks

Comment: but what are the privileges of that user? have you checked that?

Comment: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: I think you're onto something... Although permission seem good in Mysql, it looks like the user in the terminal is having permission issues... I tried updating WP CLI and got... /usr/local/bin is not writable by current user

Comment: yep, sudo is great...

Comment: Really appreciate your time... not out the woods yet, but I think I know where to look. wp cli definitely doesn't like sudo. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to prosti for pointing me in the right direction...
run the following in a terminal:

sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/bin